# Comparing Unique Values to a Range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE (FILTER(boxmod!AC2:AC, boxmod!I2:AB=concatboxmod!C2 ))
```

The intention of this formula is to take a range and compare it to a list of unique identifiers on tab sheet *concatmodbox* which SHOULD look like this upon entering a formula (right now column D is empty):

DESIRED OUTPUT (COLUMN D):

[image]

Note that Column C is using a `=UNIQUE` formula to pull the info from *boxmod column AC*.

But my formula isn't working in column D

In tab sheet *boxmod* I have the unique IDS in column AC, and the data to append to them in columns I-AB. This sheet looks like:

[image]

However my formula cannot grab the entire range of `I2:AB`, so it only works if I write the formula for a single column. Does anyone know how to make a range work in the area `{boxmod!I2:AB}`?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet with an example of the desired output. its not clear what are you after exactly. you want to join columns I-J in column D based on match from column C?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, I added some clarification above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **cell C1:**

  ```
  =UNIQUE(boxmod!AC2:AC)
  ```
- **cell D1:**

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
   VLOOKUP(C1:C, {boxmod!AC:AC, boxmod!I:J}, {2, 3}, 0))), , 999^99))))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Can you further iterate on what the following does? `{2, 3}, 0))), , 999^99`

Comment: @littlecoder sure. `{2,3}` in vlookup means to select/output 2nd and 3rd column (from 2nd vlookup parameter/range). `0` in vlookup means "exact match". and  `999^99` means a really big number so query could process that many rows

Comment: That makes more sense, I was counting A as the start point and thought it should be {9,10}, but of course the actual start is where ever you start the vlookup on. Thanks!