# Concatenating cell values to a matching cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, pivot

In the following [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KXAQTyQVFpwNKxqzvRY9hqrRujgTpZNos04d7T0yJM0/edit?usp=sharing) I am trying to grab a list of GUID keys from *tab sheet1*

[image]

and concatenate them to their respective order in *tab sheet2*. My expected output is in *tab sheet2* column B as follows:

[image]

Example: Order1 and Order3 both have a 2 in their columns so the resulting output for 2 on *tab sheet2* should be both GUID keys bbb and ccc. As is shown in *tab sheet2* column B

I used the following filter to get the unique order numbers in *tab sheet2* column A.

```
=sort(unique(transpose(split(arrayformula(concatenate
(if(len(Sheet1!A2:C)>0,Sheet1!A2:C&";",""))),";"))))
```

I tried to use the following

```
=CONCATENATE (FILTER(Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!A2:C=Sheet2!A2 ))
```

but it just errors out saying:

> FILTER range must be a single row or a single column

So is there a way to write this in order to get the range and concatenate the results? I also played around with some app script to make it work but that couldn't do the trick and it seems like a simple sheets function would do what I need.

This relates to the [following](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130280/219625)  but its the inverse of that function more or less.

Comment: not rly clear what exactly are you after. can you elaborate more and add an example of desired output?

Comment: The desired output is in link (first sentence) on sheet 2 column B, I'll add a picture as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(
 {Sheet1!A2:A; Sheet1!B2:B; Sheet1!C2:C}, 
 {Sheet1!A2:A; Sheet1!B2:B; Sheet1!C2:C}<>"")))),
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A2:C), "♠"&Sheet1!A2:C&"♦"&Sheet1!D2:D, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")),"♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2 order by Col1", 0)<>"", INDEX(
 QUERY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A2:C), "♠"&Sheet1!A2:C&"♦"&Sheet1!D2:D, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")),"♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2 order by Col1", 0), 1, ), ), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,999^99)))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow! I would have never thought of doing it that way, nice!

Comment: I notice it does not accept hyphens, for example. column A has the value 20-20 but it would return the error "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 6. Actual: 5." Is there a way to further allow special characters?

Comment: @littlecoder fixed. answer updated